# Autoresize is not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, retina-display, autoresize

[image]

I added Default-568h@2x.png  image to existing iphone4 code for iphone5 and i used autoresizingMask. But i settted frame for iphone4 is 320,480 using initWithFrame. Also i setframe for navigationBarButton is based on iphone4 screen size. Now im running my code to iphone5, the iphone4 frame size only displayed all subview's frames. For example: I used button frame is (280,5,30,30) in iphone4. This same size only displayed in iphone5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NEVER set frames manually based on a hard coded size for the screen.

Look at using `[UIScreen mainScreen].size`

Comment: How can i set particular size for the navigationbar button

Comment: The size of the navigation bar shouldn't change with the screen size. It should always be 44px tall

Comment: That's ok..But how can i set button frame dynamically iphone4 & iphone5 portrait,landscape

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would you want different navigation bar button sizes on different phones?

Comment: Because in iphone4 landscape mode width is 480. I set button frame in landscape mode is (430,5,30,30). And i set button frame in iphone5 landscape is (530,5,30,30)

Comment: So do the math off of [UIScreen mainScreen].size, or detect different screen sizes off of it and change the frame accordingly.